# how to extract bullet points from the docs using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, python-docx

I have docs which contains bullet points and I want to extract data and bullet point as it is in the docs with indentation.

- some text here

  1. some text here

I want extract it and save in other file how can i do it?

I have tried python-docx but bullet points I am not able to extract and also most of the time indentation is none

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 1):

A list item paragraph is reliably indicated by the presence of a `w:pPr/w:numPr/w:numId` subtree. You can detect this with:

```
paragraph._p.xpath("./w:pPr/w:numPr/w:numId")
```

This will produce a list containing zero or one elements. When there are zero elements, the paragraph is not a list item.

The level of the list is at:

```
paragraph._p.xpath("./w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl/@w:val")
```

This should be a string like `"0"`, `"1"`, etc.

Comment: and if I want to save them as txt like whatever lines having bullet point i want them to store in different txt file